# Javascript in IE 10 is slow

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have a problem. When i trigger this code:

```
    function addItem(){
        var select = document.getElementById("2");
        select.options.length = 0;;
        alert("Please wait...");
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(array[i]);
        }
        alert("Images loaded!");
    }
```

In Internet Explorer 10 (on Windows 8) it responds very slowly. There are an average of 35000 items average in the array, but Chrome and Firefox don't have this problem... What can I do to get this more smooth in IE? Because this is a common browser...

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `alert("Please wait...");`?

Comment: 35000 items in selectbox?? Come on.. you're killing people on slow systems, plus you're wasting bandwidth. Use some autocomplete widget, or modified select box, like http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: Yea, i have tried that Michael but no succes... And WTK, its a listbox (multiple) with names of images in it for a webcam security system

Comment: IE tends to not handle large DOM structures well and that is what you are creating with a select box with 35000 options..  In addition, you have a loop that runs 35000 times, which is also bad for performance.

Comment: Apart from performance, do you imagine having to pick something out of 35000 items in one select box?? It's crazy! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart for the silly number of items, try this

Please note that IE does not allow us to change the innerHTML of the select so I change the innerHTML of the container the select must live in for this to work

```
function addItem(){
  var select = document.getElementById("2"); // Why a numeric ID?
  var parent = select.parentNode;
  parent.innerHTML="Please wait";
  var html='<select id="2" multiple="multiple">';
  for (var i=0,n=array.length, i<n; i++) {
    html += '<option value="'+array[i]+'">'+array[i]+'</option>';
  }
  html += '</select>'
  parent.innerHTML=html;
  alert("Images loaded!");
}
```

Alternatively look at createDocumentFragment and appendChild

Comment: A word of explanation - the trick is to postpone the moment of actually inserting new options into the DOM to save on reflows and repaints.